# OptionSetType and enums

Tags: swift, enums, optionsettype

I have an enum named `ProgrammingLanguage`:

```
enum ProgrammingLanguage {
  case Swift, Haskell, Scala
}
```

Now I have a class named `Programmer` with the following property:

```
let favouriteLanguages: ProgrammingLanguage = .Swift
```

Seeing how a programmer could have several favourite languages, I'd thought it'd be nice to write something like this:

```
let favouriteLanguages: ProgrammingLanguage = [.Swift, .Haskell]
```

After a bit of research, I realized that I need to conform to `OptionSetType`, but in doing so, I've raise the following 3 errors:

**ProgrammingLanguage does not conform to**

1. `SetAlgebraType`
2. `OptionSetType`
3. `RawRepresentable`

When I saw the **Raw Representable** error, I immediately thought of associated types for enums. I wanted to be able to print the enum value anyway, so I changed my enum signature to the following:

```
case ProgrammingLanguage: String, OptionSetType {
  case Swift, Haskell, Scala
}
```

This silenced 2 of the warnings. But I'm still left with one which is that I don't conform to protocol `SetAlgebraType`.

After a bit of trial and error, I found out having the associated type of the enum as `Int` fixed it (which makes sense, since the `RawRepresentable` protocol requires you to implement an initializer of the signature `init(rawValue: Int)`). However, I'm unsatisfied with that; I want to be able to get the String representation of the enum easily.

Could someone advise me how I can do this easily, and why `OptionSetType` requires an `Int` associated type?

**Edit:**

The following declaration compiles correctly, but errors at runtime:

```
enum ProgrammingLanguage: Int, OptionSetType {
  case Swift, Scala, Haskell
}

extension ProgrammingLanguage {
  init(rawValue: Int) {
    self.init(rawValue: rawValue)
  }
}

let programmingLanguages: ProgrammingLanguage = [.Swift, .Scala]
```

Comment: I doubt that you can combine `enum` and `OptionSetType` because both `rawValue`'s interfere with each other.

Comment: @vadian It's really interesting that it compiles correctly. When running, the app crashes on the line that tries to init the option set, with the debugger showing the init called 31970 times before crashing.

Comment: I guess the code runs into an infinite loop (which doesn't matter at compile time) or something similar and then crashes on a buffer overflow.

Comment: I believe that you are confusing `associated values` with `raw values`: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID148

Comment: related https://twitter.com/johnsundell/status/906097785883242496

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit: I'm surprised at my former self for not saying this upfront at the time, but... instead of trying to force other value types into the `OptionSet` protocol (Swift 3 removed `Type` from the name), it's probably better to consider the API where you use those types and use `Set` collections where appropriate.

`OptionSet` types are weird. They are both collections and not collections — you can construct one from multiple flags, but the result is still a single value. (You can do some work to figure out a collection-of-single-flags equivalent to such a value, but depending on the possible values in the type it might not be unique.)

On the other hand, being able to have one *something*, or more than one unique *somethings*, can be important to the design of an API. Do you want users to say they have more than one favorite, or enforce that there's only one? Just how many "favorites" do you want to allow? If a user claims multiple favorites, should they be ranked in user-specific order? These are all questions that are hard to answer in an `OptionSet`-style type, but much easier if you use a `Set` type or other actual collection.

The rest of this answer a) is old, using Swift 2 names, and b) assumes that you're trying to implement `OptionSet` anyway, even if it's a bad choice for your API...

---

See the [docs for `OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html):

> Supplies convenient conformance to `SetAlgebraType` for any type whose `RawValue` is a `BitwiseOperationsType`.

In other words, you can declare `OptionSetType` conformance for any type that also adopts `RawRepresentable`. However, you gain the magic set-algebra syntax support (via operators and `ArrayLiteralConvertible` conformance) if and only if your associated raw value type is one that conforms to `BitwiseOperationsType`.

So, if your raw value type is `String`, you're out of luck — you don't gain the set algebra stuff because `String` doesn't support bitwise operations. (The "fun" thing here, if you can call it that, is that you can extend `String` to support `BitwiseOperationsType`, and if your implementation satisfies the [axioms](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_BitwiseOperationsType_Protocol/), you can use strings as raw values for an option set.)

Your second syntax errors at runtime because you've created an infinite recursion — calling `self.init(rawValue:)` from `init(rawValue:)` keeps gong until it blows the stack.

It's arguably a bug ([please file it](http://bugs.swift.org)) that you can even try that without a compile time error. Enums *shouldn't* be able to declare `OptionSetType` conformance, because:

1. The semantic contract of an enum is that it's a closed set. By declaring your `ProgrammingLanguage` enum you're saying that a value of type `ProgrammingLanguage` must be one of `Swift`, `Scala`, or `Haskell`, and not anything else. A value of "Swift and Scala" isn't in that set.
2. The underlying implementation of an `OptionSetType` is based on integer bitfields. A "Swift and Haskell" value, (`[.Swift, .Haskell]`) is really just `.Swift.rawValue | .Haskell.rawValue`. This causes trouble if your set of raw values isn't bit-aligned. That is, if `.Swift.rawValue  == 1 == 0b01`, and `.Haskell.rawValue == 2 == 0b10`, the bitwise-or of those is `0b11 == 3`, which is the same as `.Scala.rawValue`.

#### TLDR: if you want `OptionSetType` conformance, declare a struct.

And use `static let` to declare members of your type.

And pick your raw values such that members you want to be distinct from possible (bitwise-or) combinations of other members actually are.

```
struct ProgrammingLanguage: OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int

    // this initializer is required, but it's also automatically
    // synthesized if `rawValue` is the only member, so writing it
    // here is optional:
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let Swift    = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 0b001)
    static let Haskell  = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 0b010)
    static let Scala    = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 0b100)
}
```

Good ways to keep your values distinct: use binary-literal syntax as above, or declare your values with bit shifts of one, as below:

```
    static let Swift    = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let Haskell  = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let Scala    = ProgrammingLanguage(rawValue: 1 << 2)
```

Comment: Minor remark: There seems to be a default implementation for `init(rawValue: )`, it can be omitted here.

Comment: @MartinR: Yes, you get `init(rawValue:)` for free iff your only instance property is `rawValue`. But if you add more properties, you lose protocol conformances that depend on there being an initializer that's exactly `init(rawValue:)`. I find it helpful to put it there anyway — it guards against such breaking changes in the future, and it makes the protocol conformance more explicit.

Comment: Are you aware of any solution for "extend `String` to support `BitwiseOperationsType`" It would make life a lot easier...

Comment: If you really want to go down that route, see the docs I linked to for the `BitwiseOperations` protocol (Swift 3 dropped `Type` from the name). You need a `^` operator that takes two strings and returns a value that can be treated as the symmetric difference between them; e.g. `a ^ a == .allZeroes` and `a ^ .allZeroes == a`. And so on for the other operators.

Answer (score 12):

I guess you could simply achieve it in the modern way {^_^}.

```swift
protocol Option: RawRepresentable, Hashable, CaseIterable {}

extension Set where Element: Option {
    var rawValue: Int {
        var rawValue = 0
        for (index, element) in Element.allCases.enumerated() where contains(element) {
            rawValue |= (1 << index)
        }
        return rawValue
    }
}
```

... then

```swift
enum ProgrammingLanguage: String, Option {
    case Swift, Haskell, Scala
}
typealias ProgrammingLanguages = Set<ProgrammingLanguage>

let programmingLanguages: ProgrammingLanguages = [.Swift, .Haskell]
```

Reference: https://nshipster.com/optionset/

Comment: wow you are genius. You made my day! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the approach made in this mini-library: https://github.com/allexks/Options

This way all you need to do is make your enum conform to `CaseIterable` and then you can simply write:

```swift
let favouriteLanguages: Options<ProgrammingLanguage> = [.Swift, .Haskell]
```