# Is there a way to define a swift enum with power of 2 (or calculated value)

Tags: swift, enums, swift2

Is there a way to do something like this in Swift 2 ?

```
enum Placement: Int, OptionSetType {
    case
    Left   = 1 << 0,
    Right  = 1 << 1,
    Center = 1 << 2,
    Top    = 1 << 3,
    Bottom = 1 << 4,
    Middle = 1 << 5
    ;
    ....
}
```

The actual problem is that the compiler is not smart enough to see that those values are constants but more readable than the result.

So, is there some syntax sugar that permit such declaration ?

Comment: Have a look at [OptionSetType and enums](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819163/optionsettype-and-enums). For OptionSetType you need a `struct`, not an `enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Martin R said, you need struct.

```
struct Placement: OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int

    init(rawValue: Int) {
        self.rawValue = rawValue
    }

    static let Left = Placement(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let Right = Placement(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let Center = Placement(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let Top = Placement(rawValue: 1 << 3)
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `let` values for each constant instead of `var` ?